# Button TABSTOP in ownerdraw not working

Tags: mfc

I created a custom button class CMyButton inherited from CButton, then I am using the DrawItem to customize the button.

Using the custtom button, I created 3button on dialog.

The issue is that the TAB key for the button is not working. If I remove drawitem then there is no issue. Can anyone please help on this?

```
void CMyButton::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{

    CDC* pDC   = CDC::FromHandle(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);
    CRect rect = lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem;
    UINT state = lpDrawItemStruct->itemState;

    pDC->DrawFrameControl(rect, DFC_BUTTON  , DFCS_BUTTONPUSH  | DFCS );
    pDC->FillSolidRect(rect, RGB(24, 72, 76));

    pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 255, 255));



    CString strText;
    GetWindowText(strText);
    pDC->DrawText(strText,rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

}
```

Comment: How do you know the TAB key is not working?

Comment: When you remove DrawItem are you also removing the BS_OWNERDRAW style? That's the bigger change.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it.  If you make a button owner draw, then you are responsible for drawing it all the time.  This includes the focused state, etc.  See the documentation for DRAWITEMSTRUCT.itemstate.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The focus rectangle is automatically rendered for standard controls on a dialog. If you subscribe to owner-drawing, responsibility to render visual cues is shifted to the custom implementation. While <kbd>TAB</kbd>bing still works, keyboard focus remains invisible unless the implementation explicitly accounts for it.

You can use the [DRAWITEMSTRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775802.aspx) passed to your `DrawItem` method to query the item's state. If `itemState` contains the `ODS_FOCUS` flag, the control being rendered has the keyboard focus, and should produce the desired visual cue.

As a simple illustration, replace your call to `FillSolidRect` with the following code:

```
if ( state & ODS_FOCUS )
    // Control has keyboard focus -> render it green
    pDC->FillSolidRect( rect, RGB( 0, 255, 0 ) );
else
    // Control doesn't have keyboard focus -> render it red
    pDC->FillSolidRect( rect, RGB( 255, 0, 0 ) );
```

This allows you to see, that the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key does work as expected: The button control with keyboard focus is rendered green, whereas all other buttons are red.

If you are looking for a more standard appearance you can call [CDC::DrawFocusRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y0b8hs5.aspx) (or [DrawFocusRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162479.aspx)) instead.